# git checkout a remote branch says fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/user/branch'

Tags: git

I am trying to checkout another users branch locally and running into the following issue.

```
C:\ws\code\ProjectName>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/myproject/myproject.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/myproject/myproject.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master                      tracked
    user3/dev                  tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

I want to checkout the user3/dev locally. Tried

```
git branch user3dev origin/user3/dev
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/user3/dev'.
```

What am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am missing?

What I missed to is what [`git remote show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) does.
It does a [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote), which will list *all* remote branches of a distant repo.
That includes the remote tracking branches that the distant repo itself is tracking.
Among those remote tracking branch is `user3/dev`, which must correspond to a remote repo named '`user3`', branch `dev`, that your `origin` repo is linked to.

But you cannot fetch and checkout `user3` repo: you would need to know its url, and add it as your own remote to your own repo before being able to fetch and checkout one if its `user3` branch.

---

The [OP Kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322933/kiran) however [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814817/git-checkout-a-remote-branch-says-fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-origin-user-b/41814864?noredirect=1#comment70818761_41814864) what we both missed:

> user named the branch as `user3/Dev` and I had been trying `user3/dev`.

Comment: Throws the error..
`git checkout user3/dev
error: pathspec 'user3/dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: @Kiran I forgot the `fetch` first (see my edited answer), in order to create the remote tracking branch `origin/user3/dev`.

Comment: I already did the fetch. Same issue. Also just tried this: `git checkout -b user3/dev --track origin/user3/dev
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'user3/dev' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/user3/dev' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Comment: @Kiran then `user3/dev` is not a branch, but a remote named `user3` with a branch `dev`. Does `git remote -v` only list `origin`?

Comment: Yes, it lists only origin

Comment: `git remote -v
origin  ********************* (fetch)
origin  ********************* (push)`

Comment: Not sure if this makes any difference: `git version 2.10.2.windows.1`

Comment: @Kiran After reading the git remote man page, I have changed the content of my answer.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I am not sure if I understand it. git remote show just says 'origin'. git ls-remote shows the repo name followed by commit hash and the branch names with refs/heads

Comment: also, user3/dev is the name of the branch itself. user3 is not a repo, it is just using a hierarchical branch naming convention

Comment: @Kiran Then a git fetch would fetch `user3/dev` and put it under `origin/user3/dev`

Comment: Yeah, that's my understanding as well.

Comment: Damn it.. It is such a silly mistake. user named the branch as user3/Dev and I had been trying user3/dev. Apologies for the confusion. Thanks for your help though..

Comment: @Kiran Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.